# matchesId is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In an Express route, I get an array of strings called `matchesId`.

I want to loop on this array but it says `TypeError: matchesId.forEach is not a function`,

I console logged the variable and there's the array with 3 strings,

I tried to use .forEach on the array in the console of the browser and it works but not in my project!

Maybe is it related to the fact that this array of strings comes from a promise.

```
app.get("/get-last-matches", function (req, res) {
  const promise1 = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(await getMatchesByPuuid());
  });

  promise1.then((matchesId) => {
    console.log("matchesId ", matchesId); <---- returns ["EUW1_5247745187","EUW1_5247657832","EUW1_5247406125"]
    matchesId.forEach((matchId) => {
      getMatchesByMatchId(matchId);
    });
    res.send(matchesId);
  });
```

Comment: Can you try replace "promise1" by "getMatchesByPuuid" before `.then` ? The 2 is identical I think

Comment: so I comment the whole then and just put getMatchesByPuuid() ? Because I need the matchesId for the getMatchesByMatchId(matchId)

Comment: No, juste change `promise1.then((matchesId) => {` to `getMatchesByPuuid.then((matchesId) => {`.

Comment: it still doesn't work, maybe with some async await it will work..

Comment: If matchesId is really an array, we should be able to print the first element. Can you try `console.log("matchesId[0] ", matchesId[0]);` ? You will need to provide more information about the function `getMatchesByMatchId` I think. This piece of code looks good

Comment: ```console.log(matchesId[0])``` returns ```[```, that's weird. And ```console.log(matchesId)``` returns ```["EUW1_5247745187","EUW1_5247657832","EUW1_5247406125"]```

Comment: Maybe matchesId is just a string, and the first element is "[". You will need to examine the function `getMatchesByMatchId `

Comment: oh you right, I did a ```typeof matchesId``` and it's a string. Omg I need to transform this string to an array now